# MVC Routing .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my earlier .net application I used to have the below routing in the route.config

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { tenant = "GRE", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now I am moving to .Net Core and somehow I am not able to setup the similar routing in the startup.cs

I have tried as below this but it never hits.

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {  
                routes.MapRoute("testroute", "{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { tenant = "GRE", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

            });
```

HomeController.cs

```
public IActionResult Index(string tenant)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Appreciate any sort of help or hints on how to make it work

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Your `id` parameter, which is optional your asp.net mvc code, is not optional in asp.net core code and have no default, for that reason it does not match. To make it optional, add "?" to the name, or set a default:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("testroute", "{tenant}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { tenant = "GRE", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

});
```

You can also set defaults inline, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("testroute", "{tenant=GRE}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: For anybody else benifit now I am able to get my tenat from the URL on the Action

http://localhost:25623/GRE/Home/Index  OR  
  http://localhost:25623/TOEFL/Home/Index , 

I receive either GRE or TOEFL based on that being invoked.